# How can I make a mail button for Android

Tags: android

I want to make button that when I press on it it wil open the default email client and makes it possible to send a mail to a pre-defined email adres, like a mailto: method.

I cant't figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the link to find all the methods to start an activity to Compose mail.

http://snipt.net/Martin/android-intent-usage/